# how to block access to directories in wamp

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, wamp

I want to block the direct access to directories in the www folder of my wamp server so that no one can directly access the files which are residing there. 
Example:
There is a folder in www named "folder". This folder contains a file "page.php" and several images and css files. There is no index file in this folder. Now when the user enters ..../folder/ whole directory will be accessible to user. But I want to hide the directory list from user. But page.php should be accessible when opened through the any other page (via hyperlink)
Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it, you probably still want those items to be accessible so that pages referencing those files will still load. You just don't want Apache to list out the files when navigating to that folder.

Apache calls these pages "directory indexes". You can turn it off for a specific folder (and sub folders) by adding to the [`.htaccess`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) file for that folder an entry:

```
Options -indexes
```

More details on the `Options` directive and `.htaccess` files here:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options